# How to turn comma separator in queryString to pipe separator only at the end

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, query-string, querystringparameter

So i currently have an API i'm hitting with queryParams. The params are colour and i'm calling the api like this:

`{apiUrl}?firstQuery=someQuery&colour=Blue,Green`

Where the above request will request items with Blue and Green colours from the server.

Now sometimes the colours can get a bit tricky and cause me problems, specially long colours that already have commas in the colour description/text itself.

Here is a list of the long/problematic colours:

```
const coloursWithCommas = [
    'Red, Blue, Yellow and Green Play of Colour',
    'Red, Green, Blue And Orange Play Of Colour',
    'Orange With Green, Red, Yellow And Blue Play Of Colour',
    'Green, Blue And Yellow Play Of Colour',
    'Purple-Red, White and Blue-Green',
  ];
```

As you can see in my API call that i need a comma separator to be able to send multiple colours at once but there are colours that already have commas in it. Therefore this request fails to get the desired colours:
`{apiUrl}?firstQuery=someQuery&colour=Blue,Green,Red, Blue, Yellow and Green Play of Colour`

As you can see that i'm trying to get 3 different colours in 1 request which is **Blue**, **Green** and **Red, Blue, Yellow and Green Play of Colour**

To combat this issue the API now accepts | pipe separator instead of comma to send multiple colours whilst respecting each colour value that contains commas.

So now the new api call is:

`{apiUrl}?firstQuery=someQuery&colour=Blue|Green|Red, Blue, Yellow and Green Play of Colour|Purple-Red, White and Blue-Green`

This would successfully return me **Blue**, **Green**, **Red, Blue, Yellow and Green Play of Colour**,**Purple-Red, White and Blue-Green**

I have written this helper function:

```
const convertCommaToPipe = (queryInput) => {
  let queryStringName = queryInput.split('=')[0];
  let queryString = queryInput.split('=')[1];

  const coloursWithCommas = [
    'Red, Blue, Yellow and Green Play of Colour',
    'Red, Green, Blue And Orange Play Of Colour',
    'Orange With Green, Red, Yellow And Blue Play Of Colour',
    'Green, Blue And Yellow Play Of Colour',
    'Purple-Red, White and Blue-Green',
  ];

  if(!coloursWithCommas.includes(queryString)){
    queryString = queryString.replace(',', '|');
  } else{
    const longColourIndex = coloursWithCommas.findIndex((text) => text === queryString);
    queryString = coloursWithCommas[longColourIndex] + '|';
  }

  return queryStringName + '=' + queryString;
}
```

So that I can be able turn a queryString from:
`colour=Blue,Green, Blue And Yellow Play Of Colour,Orange With Green, Red, Yellow And Blue Play Of Colour`

to:

`&colour=Blue|Green, Blue And Yellow Play Of Colour|Orange With Green, Red, Yellow And Blue Play Of Colour`

The queryInput from the helper function will always start with `colour=Blue` or `colour=Green, Blue And Yellow Play Of Colour` and it will then build/append one at time and it can then have the full query like `colour=Blue,Green,Red, Blue, Yellow and Green Play of Colour` give that the user has clicked on those 3 colours.

It won't be receiving all the colour queries at once, it will be appended as the user clicks the UI. That seems to be what's causing my function to not fully work 100%. Please advise the best way to achieve what i'm trying to given the circumstances.

Comment: Is there any reason why you are converting commas to pipes instead of building the URI with pipes in the first place? You should always have data in the most appropriate data structure as long as possible. Keep an array (or `Set`) of colours, not an URI; then build the URI when you need to send a request.

Comment: `replace(string, string)` only works on first instance found. Use replaceAll() or a regex with `g` flag in replace()

Comment: @Amadan it's because it's related to a filter component in the UI. The requirements are that the filter is done live, rather than building up the filter query. That's why i can't pre-build the URI. It must be created/generated as the user is clicking/generating it

Comment: Could you please provide an example of exactly what that `coloursWithCommas` object should look like after all the comma/pipe splits have been implemented? Just trying to wrap my head around this still

Comment: You can still have a live response while storing the underlying data in a more appropriate structure. If you can't, then then consider explaining your architecture in more detail. I never said "pre-build the URI" — I said to build it just before you need to make a request. If you need to make the request at every user click, then build the URI at every user click.

Comment: @Jim41Mavs And exactly that user click should generate an URI with pipes. Can you show us that UI code please?

Comment: @BrandonMcConnell

If i wanted all the colours in the `coloursWithCommas` then it should like look this: 

`colour=Red, Blue, Yellow and Green Play of Colour|Red, Green, Blue And Orange Play Of Colour|Orange With Green, Red, Yellow And Blue Play Of Colour|Green, Blue And Yellow Play Of Colour|Purple-Red, White and Blue-Green`

Comment: @BrandonMcConnell
If i wanted all of the above + a colour with no commas such as Blue it should look like this:

`colour=Red, Blue, Yellow and Green Play of Colour|Red, Green, Blue And Orange Play Of Colour|Orange With Green, Red, Yellow And Blue Play Of Colour|Green, Blue And Yellow Play Of Colour|Purple-Red, White and Blue-Green|Blue`

Comment: @Bergi The UI code is a bit long to write here, but basically each time user clicks a filter, and object created like this:  `{ colour: ['Blue'] }` ,  `{ colour: ['Blue', 'Red, Blue, Yellow and Green Play of Colour'] }`, `{colour: ['Blue', 'Pink'], shape: ['Round', 'Square']}`. Then i use this function to create the queryString `Object.keys(filterObject).map((key) => key + '=' + filterObject[key]).join('&');`

Comment: FYI guys, i achieved what i wanted by doing this:

`Object.keys(filterObject).map((key) => key + '=' + filterObject[key].join('|')).join();`

Comment: @Jim41Mavs Exactly that is what I meant :-) Don't forget to `encodeURIComponent` the keys and values though.

Comment: Good catch/reminder! Thanks @Bergi

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest you change the API it self(assuming it's ur API).
You should use **PUT** or **POST** and pass the colors as array of string.

Comment: What is an "array of string"? How is it different in PUT or POST?